# Getting values from foreach

Tags: php, foreach-loop-container

i have code which was written by a previous developer in our organization which says:

```
< ?php
foreach($response as $key => $value) {
?>      

<tr>

<td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php

}

?>
```

i am very new to php and i dont know how to get values of  $key[1]...$key[20] & $value[1]...$value[20] from this above code, since the above code writes 20 lines of values

I dont know if i am able to express this code problem in front of you correctly or not. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem here? Do you want indexes to be printed as well?

Comment: The foreach is iterating through all values. Why do you need indexes?

Comment: What is in your array `$response`?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to have numerical indices..?

```
$key = array_keys($response);
$value = array_values($response);
```

Then you can use

> $key[1]...$key[20] & $value[1]...$value[20]

Comment: superb Lukas!! thanks for the help... this is what i was looking for. you are a star !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
< ?php
$keysarray = array();
$valuesarray = array();
int i = 0;
foreach($response as $key => $value) {
?>      

<tr>

<td><?php $keysarray[i]= $key; echo $key; ?></td>
<td><?php $valuesarray[i]= $value; echo $value; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
i++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea with a foreach loop is so you don't need to access the various indexes inside the array.

in your example, $response is an array.

during each iteration, the key/index of the array is assigned to $key and the value is assigned to $value.

eg.

```
$response = array('hello', 'goodbye');
// which is essentially the same as:
$response = array(0 => 'hello', 1 => 'goodbye');
```

during the first iteration of the foreach loop:

```
// first item in the array has an index of 0 and value of 'hello'
$key == 0;
$value == 'hello';
```

during pass two:

```
$key == 1;
$value == 'goodbye';
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array `$response` is `array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");` then,

```
<?php

$response= array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");

foreach($response as $key => $value) {
?>      

<tr>

<td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php

}
```

Will Out put,

```
Peter 35 
Ben 37 
Joe 43
```

If `$response` is `array("35","37","43");`

then It will Out put,

```
0 35 
1 37 
2 43
```

In first case, Key will be as you given. It is known as `Associative Arrays`. Second, keys will be default from 0. It is `Numeric arrays`. No big deal.